# Restoring only one file from a backup set

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have a job which takes backups but rather than making a new file each time, it appends to the existing file.

When I use `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM <backup_device>` I get three records as output which is exactly what I expect. Now I am having trouble in restoring one file from the backup set.

Any idea how we can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BACKUP DATABASE [...] TO  DISK = N'new backup name' WITH INIT`

or check script for *Automated Database Backups* in this [post](http://blog.devart.com/sql-server-typical-maintenance-plans-automated-database-backups.html)

Comment: Thanks for saving my time, it helped me a lot.

Comment: @Jason Clark you are welcome ;) glad heat that my post will be helpful for you